# Adobe AIR FPS adjustment in AS3 fails in AIR but works in flash build

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, frame-rate

I have a game that works great in flash and changes the FPS during gameplay.

When compiled to AIR this feature no longer works.

This is the code being used.
`stage.frameRate += 1;`

Comment: How are you confirming that it no longer works? - What is the actually frame rate you're attempting to set it to?

Comment: Does your application have more than one window that your changing the frame rate for? (AIR only supports one framerate for ALL windows)

Comment: I am starting at 20 fps and slowly increasing to 60 fps for gameplay difficulty progression.

Comment: I am using 1 window yes.  For some reason it just doesnt work in air.

Comment: I tried a simple test in `Flash CC 2014`, worked as expected. (Published as runtime-embedded AIR 13.0 application)